# Extension on swift mutable dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to create an extension on mutable dictionaries of types `[NSObject:AnyObject]`

Here is the syntax for an immutable dictionary extension in Swift for `[NSObject:AnyObject]`:

```
extension Dictionary where Key:NSObject, Value:AnyObject {
    func addSomething() {
        // Fails
        self["ExampleKey"] = "ExampleValue"
    }    
}
```

However, in this case `self` cannot be appended to, because the extension works on immutable dictionaries. The question is what syntax is missing in order to make an extension for exclusively mutable dictionaries.

Edit: Updated to address ambiguity

**Update**:

By adding the `mutating` prefix to `addSomething`, I can operate on only mutable dictionarys. Yay! However, the function still is not working

```
mutating func addSomething() {
    // Error: Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<Key, Value>' with an index of type 'String'
    self["ExampleKey"] = "ExampleValue"
}
```

If I cast `"ExampleKey"` to a Key, I get another error:

```
mutating func addSomething() {
    let key = "ExampleKey" as! Key
    // Error: Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
    self[key] = "ExampleValue"
}
```

Still researching how to get this simple addition to work...

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: or post code that is not working...

Comment: or respond to activity on your question... Happy to help, and I am sure the downvoters will be happy to upvote if you improve the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works

```
extension Dictionary where Key:NSObject, Value:AnyObject {
    mutating func addSomething(forKey key:Key, value: Value) {
        self[key] = value
    }
}

var dict = [NSString:NSString]()

dict.addSomething(forKey: "test", value: "some test")
```

Comment: Yes! The cast to Value was what I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3+ I'm using this extension:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {
  mutating func set(value optionalValue: Any?, forKey key: String) {
    guard let value = optionalValue else { return }

    self[key] = value
  }
}
```

Cheers!